# STUN MESSAGE-INTEGRITY dummy definition

Tags: stun

in RFC5389 MESSAGE-INTEGRITY calculation includes itself but **with dummy content**
**dummy content** is not defined
how can MESSAGE-INTEGRITY be verified without knowing **dummy content** value?
why would MESSAGE-INTEGRITY calculation include itself?
is't it faster to calculate MESSAGE-INTEGRITY and equally secure if it didn't include itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the MESSAGE-INTEGRITY attribute itself is not part of the hash, you can append whatever you want for the last 20 bytes. Just replace it with the hash of all the bytes leading up to the attribute itself.

The algorithm is basically this:

- Let `L` be the original size of the STUN message byte stream. Should be the same as the value for MESSAGE LENGTH in the STUN message header.
- Append a 4 byte header onto the STUN message followed by 20 null bytes
- Adjust the LENGTH field of the STUN message to account for these 24 new bytes.
- Compute the HMAC/SHA1 of the first `L` bytes of the message (all but the 24 bytes you just appended).
- replace the 20 null bytes with the 20 bytes of the computed hash

And as discussed in comments, the bytes don't have to be null bytes, they can be anything - since they aren't included in the hash computation.

There's an implementation of MESSAGE-INTEGRITY for both short-term and long-term credentials on my Github: [here](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/d2d06a6d002d1e2fba312cf4993b08bb57a0346b/stuncore/stunbuilder.cpp#L476) and [here](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/d2d06a6d002d1e2fba312cf4993b08bb57a0346b/stuncore/stunbuilder.cpp#L527)

Comment: where did you find the definition of **dummy content** as zeros?

Comment: Sorry - I had to go re-read the spec (and my code) and change my answer.  Basically, you're hashing everything up to and before the MESSAGE-INTEGRITY attribute itself.  So you can literally use any content you want since it won't be included as part of the hash.

Comment: The trick is that you take the original STUN message. Hack the LENGTH header by adding 24 to it.  Then HMAC/SHA1 the whole message. Then append the MESSAGE-INTEGRITY header with hash.

Comment: you say **MESSAGE-INTEGRITY attribute itself is not part of the hash** but RFC5389 says **The text used as input to HMAC is the STUN message, including the header, up to and including the attribute preceding the MESSAGE-INTEGRITY attribute**

Comment: if your implementation works then that means that RFC5389 is wrong and RFC5389 
 has at the top something that says **Errata Exist**

Comment: wait **attribute preceding the MESSAGE-INTEGRITY**  that means it does not include MESSAGE-INTEGRITY...my definition of "preceding" was not clear

Comment: your answer was about how to calculate it but my issue was about all the problems created by "a MESSAGE-INTEGRITY having a calculation that includes itself" but that was wrong it actually does not include itself so the anwer to my question is just **the calculation does not include itself**

Comment: I don't know what your comments are saying.  :)  But I do know that I've implemented most all of RFC 5389 and validated it against the test cases specified in RFC 5769. Go with what the code does. My quoted answer is just a quick interpretation of what the spec says and what the code does. They seem to reconcile with each other. It's been a few years since I originally wrote it.